# All of my tokens in flex/bison are being shown as undeclared

Tags: c, bison, yacc, flex-lexer, lex

Im building my files with
yacc -d calclang.y

```
%{ 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void yyerror(const char *str);


%}

%union 
{
    int ival; 
    float fval;
    char* word;
}
%start line
%type <word> wexp
%type <ival> iexp
%type <fval> fexp

%left PLUS MINUS
%left STAR DIV MOD
%left POW
%token GT
%token LT
%token ASGN
%token LP
%token RP
%token LB
%token RB
%token NOT
%token GTEQ
%token LTEQ
%token EQTO
%token NOTEQ
%token HORN
%token QMARK
%token <word> WORD
%token <fval> FLOAT
%token <ival> INTEGER


%%

line    : HORN wexp QMARK   {   printf("=\t%s", $2);    }
        | HORN iexp QMARK   {   printf("=\t%d", $2);    }
        | HORN fexp QMARK   {   printf("=\t%f", $2);    }
        ;

iexp    : iexp MINUS iexp   { $$ = $1 - $3;             }
        | iexp PLUS iexp    { $$ = $1 + $3;             }
        | INTEGER           { $$ = $1;                  }
        ;

fexp    : FLOAT             { $$ = $1;                  }
        ;

wexp    : WORD              { $$ = $1;                  }
        ;
%%


int main(){
    return yyparse();
}

void yyerror(const char *str)
{
        printf("error: %s\n",str);
}
```

and

flex calclang.l

```
%option noyywrap

%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

%%
"horn" | "HORN" {   return HORN;                                }
[1-9][0-9]*     {   return INTEGER; yylval.ival = atoi(yytext); }
[0-9]+"."[0-9]+ {   return FLOAT;   yylval.fval = atof(yytext); }
">="            {   return GTEQ;                                }
"<="            {   return LTEQ;                                }
"=="            {   return EQTO;                                }
"!="            {   return NOTEQ;                               }
"+"             {   return PLUS;                                }
"-"             {   return MINUS;                               }
"*"             {   return STAR;                                }
"/"             {   return DIV;                                 }
"^"             {   return POW;                                 }
"%"             {   return MOD;                                 }
">"             {   return GT;                                  }
"<"             {   return LT;                                  }
"("             {   return LP;                                  }
")"             {   return RP;                                  }
"="             {   return ASGN;                                }
"{"             {   return LB;                                  }
"}"             {   return RB;                                  }
"!"             {   return NOT;                                 }
"?"             {   return QMARK;                               }
[a-zA-Z]*       {   return WORD;    yylval.word = yytext;       }
[ \t\n\r]       {;                                              }
.               {;                                              }
%%
```

Then I'm using 
gcc y.tab.c lex.yy.c -o test

but I receive the following error message:

```
calclang.l:9:10: error: ‘INTEGER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:9:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
calclang.l:9:19: error: ‘yylval’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:10:10: error: ‘FLOAT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:11:10: error: ‘GTEQ’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:12:10: error: ‘LTEQ’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:13:10: error: ‘EQTO’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:14:10: error: ‘NOTEQ’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:15:10: error: ‘PLUS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:16:10: error: ‘MINUS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:17:10: error: ‘STAR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:18:10: error: ‘DIV’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:19:10: error: ‘POW’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:20:10: error: ‘MOD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:21:10: error: ‘GT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:22:10: error: ‘LT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:23:10: error: ‘LP’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:24:10: error: ‘RP’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:25:10: error: ‘ASGN’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:26:10: error: ‘LB’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:27:10: error: ‘RB’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:28:10: error: ‘NOT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:29:10: error: ‘QMARK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
calclang.l:30:10: error: ‘WORD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I've looked at other posts, and they said to have the #include y.tab.h
but I already have that. So I've hit a roadblock. Why are all of my tokens undeclared?
Thank you!

Comment: How about checking the generated `y.tab.h` file to verify that it defines all the expected symbols, and checking the generated `lex.yy.c` to verify that it in fact `#include`s `y.tab.h`?  Also, does the compiler emit any other warning or error messages before the ones you present?

Comment: the y.tab.h has all the defines, but lex.yy.c doesnt have the #include for y.tab.h. Any theories as to why would this happen?

Comment: @ChrisPhillips: The include is not at the beginning of lex.yy.c. Are you sure it is not present? It might be several hundred lines into the file; you'll need to search with a text editor or grep. It all works ok on my system; what version of flex and bison are you using?

Comment: flex 2.5.35
bison 2.5
-edit: i just ran a search, and the include isnt in lex.yy.c

Comment: @ChrisPhillips: That's the same version of flex as I tried it with, and I copied-and-pasted your flex file. The include shows up at line 486. (There are various problems with your flex file, but I don't see any which will interfere with the inclusion of the `%{...}%` block.)

Comment: Your code works for me (in the sense that a program can successfully be built from the generated files).  If it's not working for you then perhaps your intermediate files are stale -- try running flex again, and make sure that lex.yy.c is in fact regenerated.  Also, make sure that there's no possibility of confusion between different source or intermediate files of the same name in different directories.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Thank you. I moved the .y and .l files into a different directory, re-compiled, and the include is now there. Now all that's left to do is fix the REAL syntax errors haha.

Answer (score 2):

Use the -d option when you compile the yacc file. the -d option will write the y.tab.h header file. it is because of that lex is not identifying any of the tokens

```
    $lex filename.l
    $yacc -d filename.y
    $cc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -ll -ly
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly related to your question (as far as I know) but it definitely needs to be fixed:

```
"horn" | "HORN" {   return HORN;                                }
```

Flex regular expressions cannot have spaces. This is being parsed by flex as a `|` action, not as a regex operator, although it's not a valid `|` action either because that should be the last token on the line. I think that most versions of flex will just ignore the rest of the line, but I'm by no means sure. You should remove the spaces:

```
"horn"|"HORN"   {   return HORN;                                }
```

Also, the action here (and in some other lines):

```
[1-9][0-9]*     {   return INTEGER; yylval.ival = atoi(yytext); }
```

should generate a warning when compiled, because the statement following a `return` statement is never executed. (You should use `-Wall` in your gcc command to see the warnings.) In other words, the action in normal C code, so the assignment to `yylval.ival` cannot be executed.

Comment: The `HORN` case is fine.  It should be interpreted by `flex` as two patterns and two actions, with the action of the first pattern being `|` (a special action meaning "the same action as for the next pattern").  I prefer to make that clearer, though, by breaking it into two lines, each with one pattern and one action.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: flex 2.5.35 ignores all tokens after the `|`, which is why `HORN` doesn't appear in the list of undefined symbols. TIAS.

Comment: You're right about the observed behavior, which I can confirm with the same version of `flex`.  This is, however, contrary to the documentation (which I got slightly wrong, too).  The action is documented to be *the remainder of the line*, possibly extending to multiple lines if the first contains a `{`.  Flex ought not to drop part of the line without at least emitting a diagnostic.  Anyway, the problem could be fixed either by removing the spaces from the pattern or by splitting the line after the `|`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: That's correct. The documentation says that the fall-through action is produced by "An action *consisting solely* of a vertical bar", so the OP's use of `|` is not a valid use of `|`, as I said in the answer :) How flex versions handle incorrect input is undocumented.